# Is Halting problem only applicable to infinite languages

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Is the halting problem, only applicable for infinite languages?

I assume that if the language is finite, then we can search over all words?

Comment: What do you mean by "applicable"? The halting problem makes sense for any language.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I meant that if the language was finite, then you could scan all possible solutions? For example, if L has one element, then we can know if it will halt by checking if the input is equal to the one element in L?

Comment: The halting problem accepts as input a (description of) a Turing machine $M$ and an input $x$, and the goal is to decide whether $M$ halts on $x$. If you fix $M$ then it's no longer the halting problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What do you mean by "Fix M" ?  To re-say what I think you said: The Halting problem is a problem that takes in any arbitrary Turing Machine and input. If this is correct, then if the M arbitrarily chosen is defined over a finite language, then can we not just check the set?

Comment: The halting problem accepts as an input a Turing machine $M$ and an input $x$, and the goal is to decide whether $M$ halts on $x$. Another formulation fixes $x$: the input is just a Turing machine $M$, and the goal is to decide whether $M$ halts on the empty input (say). Anything else is not the halting problem. You mention "the language", but I'm not sure how it fits in this picture.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Oh I see. I think maybe I was mixing the halting problem with the un-decidability of the halting problem. Can I reformulate and say that un-decidability of the halting problem is only applicable when the language is infinite?

Comment: You're fixing $M$. Once you fix $M$, it's no longer the halting problem. What you are really saying is, for some languages $L(M)$ is decidable (where $L(M)$ is the set of inputs on which $M$ halts), and for others it's not.

Comment: Oh, I see. By fixing the language, I am fixing M because a Turing Machine only accepts one language. So what I am doing is basically passing in a fixed set of (M,x) which I know will pass. Whereas the halting problem states that we need to pass in any (M,x) @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Even if I did it this way, I believe it would still be wrong because the halting problem says we need *one* algorithm to solve *all* instances of the problem, I think

Comment: Right, if you fix $M$ then you change the problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Got it, thank you!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If you are free, could you check out my other question on Turing machines? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110913/questions-about-turing-machine